# Unexpected behaviour from TryCatchFinally block?

Tags: c#, .net

Below I have coded a simple method to attempt a connection to the server. It worked fine up until recently when I noticed that inside the finally block, _socket was null, which doesn't make sense.

Look at this line

```
_socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
```

It throws an exception because _socket is null, but _socket gets assigned in the try block. If it somehow failed, then it goes into the catch block, setting `successful` to false and not running it.

But it seems to be running finally even if the catch block is thrown? In this example, it successfully connected, but how can _socket me null, I'm assigning it.

```
public void Connect()
{
    var successful = true;

    try
    {

        if (_socket.IsConnected() || _isConnecting)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isConnecting = true;

        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, _port));
        _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        successful = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        _isConnecting = false;

        if (successful)
        {
            _socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(_socket.IsConnected()` will make you land in the `catch` then in the `finally` is `_socket` is `null`. And this is before the line `_socket = new Socket(...)`

Comment: @Rafalon: and, important: `successful = true` as well

Comment: @Stefan this is in my opinion less important than the fact he tries to access a method of an object without knowing if it is `null` or not

Comment: `_socket.IsConnected()` returns false if socket is null, this isn't the cause.

Comment: You set the `_socket_` to a new Socket *after* you check  if  `_socket.IsConnected()` so the first time you come here, it will be null. (Unless something else sets it)

Comment: `_socket.IsConnected() returns false if socket is null` that seems unlikely.

Comment: When you say the socket is connected method "returns false if socket is null,"  are you sure? What type is the `_socket`?

Comment: @Stefan I just realized what you meant by `successful = true` being important. Indeed, we generally set ***negative defaults*** so if something goes wrong, we won't have false positives

Answer (score 6):

> But it seems to be running finally even if the catch block is thrown?

That's exactly how a `finally` block works.  A `finally` block is *always* executed, exception case or otherwise.

(Well, perhaps not *always*.  If there's a power failure, if the environment somehow completely breaks, if the host system forcibly terminates the process with extreme prejudice, etc.  But as long as the code is executing, a `finally` block will execute.)

There are a number of things to take note of in your code...

1) Stop assuming success until something is actually successful:

```
var successful = false;

// and in the try block...
_socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
successful = true;
```

2) Check if an object is `null` before using it:

```
if (_socket == null)
{
    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}
if (_socket.IsConnected() || _isConnecting)
{
    return;
}

_isConnecting = true;

_socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, _port));
_socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
```

3) You weren't catching the exception in the first place.  Your `catch` block only looks for a `SocketException`, but your code was throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point that any exception other than SocketException causes successful to remain true in the finally block.

Comment: @spodger: That's a good point.  The OP seems to be under a number of logical misconceptions.  (1) How `finally` works, (2) How a `NullReferenceException` differs from a `SocketException`, (3) Not to use an object a couple lines of code before it's initialized, (4) Not to assume success.  I'll see if I can reasonably update the answer.

Comment: have fun and good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to know, that `finally` block is executed just before exception is thrown.

So, in case when there's uncaught exception (other than `SocketException`), then the `catch` block won't be executed, so `successful` remains `true`, when entering `finally` block.

So there's possibility, that you get an exception before initializing `_socket`, then going straight to `finally` block and getting another exception.

If you'd change `catch (SocketException e)` to `catch (Exception e)` it would work as you expect.

Comment: This should be the answer, although it could do with being worded better.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not get how `finally` works. The `finally` block executes *always, no matter what happens in the `try`/`catch` blocks*. You could put a `return` statement in the `try` or `catch` and the `finally` will execute. That's its whole purpose.
You can read more about it [in the msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da8ft1w2.aspx).

I'm guessing that you would achieve the desired effect by simply removing the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally-block` in a `try-catch-finally` is used typically as clean-up. You want this to **always** execute - whether an exception is caught or not is irrelevant. To be clear, if the application reaches a `try-block` with a `finally-block`, it will always execute the `finally-block` after the `try-block` and/or `catch-block` has executed. This includes when there exists a *return* within the `try-block`.

An example of this would be seen in multi-threading. The `try-block` you could obtain the lock for a certain mutable object. The `catch-block` is a fail-safe just in case of unexpected issues in your calculations (i.e. `ParseException`, `NullPointerException`). The `finally-block` would contain the logic for releasing the lock on the mutable object. This is **vital** as it avoids potential for deadlocking because the finally will **always** execute. Without this functionality, clean-up could be rendered impossible with use of `try-catch-blocks`.

Another great example could be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) from Microsoft with streams. This scenario utilizes the `finally-block` to ensure that the stream is closed whether the previous block finishes correctly or not.

With regards to your specific example, I think the code could be refactored a bit.

```
public bool Connect() {
    if(_socket == null) // Initialize the _socket object
    if(_socket.IsConnected()) return true;

    try {
        _socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, _port));
        return true;
    }
    catch(SocketException e) {
        // Error handling such as logging, error prompt, or reconfigure & retry
        return false;
    }
}

public bool Send(string msg) {
    try {
        if(!Connect()) // Throw Exception
        // Insert sending logic
        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Error Handling
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        // Maybe insert close socket logic
    }
}
```